# 3dcart SOAP API response

Tags: php, api, soap

I have been trying to make a 3dcart API interogation in PHP.

```
<?php

/** define the SOAP client using the url for the service**/

$SoapiClient = new soapclient('http://api.3dcart.com/cart.asmx?WSDL', array('trace' => 1));

/*array trace helps so that we can see previous soap transactions for details see php.net documentation*/

/**create an array of parameters for geting the info of a customer**/

$storeUrl="store.3dcartstores.com/"; //the provided store URL

$userKey="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"; // the provided password

$callBackURL=""; // the URL in which the result will be put

$batchSize=1; // the batch number

$startNum="2"; // the starting number

$customersFilter=""; // the customer filter

$thearray = array('storeUrl' => $storeUrl, 'userKey' => $userKey,

'callBackURL' => $callBackURL, 'batchSize' => $batchSize, 'customersFilter' => $customersFilter, 'startNum' => $startNum);

/** call the service, passing the parameters and the name of the operation **/

$result = $SoapiClient->getCustomer($thearray); 

/** a quick test **/

if (is_soap_fault($result)):

echo '<h1>ERRRO</h1><pre>';

print_r($result);

echo '</pre>';

else:

echo '<h1>Working FINE</h1><pre>';

print_r($result->getCustomerResult->any);

echo '</pre>';

endif;

?>
```

Now my problem starts here, the result is a string with all the information and it is without spaces nor formated as an array or object.

ex response:

> Working FINE
>
> 2NameFname Str. Nr.17 12Las
>   VegasNevada400500USAHome00101234567890user@mail.comNameFname Str.
>   Nr.17 c12Las
>   VegasNevada400500USAHome00101234567890/7/2015123456789008/7/20151

How can I get this info as an array or object?

Second question is what are the commands of the `customersFilter`? What does it do and how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using php's simplexml_load_string() function to return the string as a SimpleXMLElement object:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php
http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php

`customersFilter` allows filtering the results by email address.